# Where is the connectionstring stored in an MSAccess app? adp and/or accdb

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 app that has linked tables. During development I have pointed to a dev DB. Now I would like to point the Access app to a production db. Where is the connection information stored and what is the correct way to change it?

If it were a .Net app or web app I would change it in the App.Config or Web.Config. Is there an equivalent in Access?

Comment: No 2013 can't. I am in the midst of a project to upgrade to Accdb files.